# Dynamic allocation pass by value (C90)

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, pass-by-value, c89

I have the following struct I would like to initialize:

```
typedef struct Node {
struct Node *next;
int data;
}Node;
```

And the following function prototype I need to use to initialize it(using dynamic memory allocation):

```
void initialize_node(Node *in){
 in= calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
}
```

After the function call ends, in is still not initialized. How do i fix this?

Comment: Can you update your description to include what you have so far for initialize_node and describe which part specifically you are having a problem with?

Comment: First, `Node *next;` --> `struct Node *next;`. And With this signature, you can not set an object dynamically allocated to the caller's pointer.

Comment: Please do not repeat the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782361/setting-the-value-in-a-struct-pas-by-value-issue-c90).

Comment: I've updated the question, the missing "struct" was a typo @BLUEPIXY

Comment: What are your issues? Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this specific case @BLUEPIXY has clearly pinned down what your issue is.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY my bad